# Как создать меню с выбором функций на Python?

Tags: python, menu

Мне нужно, чтобы после выбор каждой функции, у меня заново открывалось меню, и только при выборе нуля в меню, он выходил из неё.
Пример:

```
print("1. выбор действия один")
print("2. выбор действия два")
print("3. выбор действия три")
print("0. выйти из программы")
default = input("Выберите пункт: ")
```

Comment: Ну, зациклите код из вопроса, а из `input` принимайте значение в переменную, в которой и проверяйте введенное значение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while True:
    print("1. выбор действия один")
    print("2. выбор действия два")
    print("3. выбор действия три")
    print("0. выйти из программы")
    cmd = input("Выберите пункт: ")
    
    if cmd == "1":
        # действие 1
    elif cmd == "2":
        # действие 2
    elif cmd == "3":
        # действие 3
    elif cmd == "0":
        break
    else:
        print("Вы ввели не правильное значение"
```